# How do you set $rootScope within Angular Service function?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, angularjs-scope, rootscope

I'm having trouble setting $rootScope for Angularjs.

Below is my function

```
App.controller('Controller',
function (UtilityService, $rootScope) {

var setSession = function () {

  $rootScope.test = "yes"; // <-- I get this

  UtilityService.getSession().success(
  function () {       
    $rootScope.test = "No"; // <-- I don't get this How do I get/set this value?       
  });      
};

setSession();   

});
```

**Additional Info:**

One of the ways that might work is to set up a service that is interacted between multiple controllers. Does anybody know how to do this with the service returning an http.get json object.

I'm having trouble getting a dynamic scope in my controller that is instantiated within a service.

Comment: I would use $scope in your case, both accesses to "test" are in same controller.

Comment: So can you set $rootScope to $scope? I need to access the "scope" in a different controller.

Comment: Might want to use a service to share data between controllers so you don't pollute `$rootScope`. But `$rootScope` should be accessible.

Comment: @NeilSmith Smith - How do you do that? Do you have an example?

Comment: There's plenty of examples out there. Just do a quick search for angular services.

Comment: @NeilSmith Been doing it for hours now.

Comment: Posted a full answer with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to address my issue I had to

1) Pass $rootScope into my 2nd controller

> App.controller($rootScope) {

2) Set my 2nd controller's function to $rootScope

> $rootScope.functionCall = function () {};

3) Set my passed value to $rootScope ($rootScope.orderId)

> ```
> $rootScope.functionCall = function () {
>  Service.getItems($rootScope.orderId).success(
>     function(results) {
>       $scope.items = results;
>     });
> };
> ```

---

4) within my utility controller, I loop through my results, parsing them, and setting them to $rootScope as you can see in #3 I am initializing "$rootScope.orderId"

> ```
> angular.forEach(results, function (value, key) {
>       if (key != null) {
>         $parse(key).assign($rootScope, value);
>       }
>     });
> ```

**5) I am re-calling the controller's function from within my service call!** This is what did the magic for me putting my variable "in scope"

> $rootScope.functionCall();

6) I am also testing to see if the function exist cause different pages utilize the utility code but may not have the function to execute

> if (typeof $rootScope.functionCall == 'function')

```
var setSession = function () {

  UtilityService.getSession().success(
  function (results) {             

    // Place the rootscope sessions in scope
    angular.forEach(results, function (value, key) {
      if (key != null) {
        $parse(key).assign($rootScope, value);
      }
    });                

    // Have to bypass "scope" issues and thus have to execute these fns()
    if (typeof $rootScope.functionCall == 'function') {
      $rootScope.functionCall();
    }

});

};
setSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote before I would use $scope when possible and if you need to share data across multiple controllers you can use a service. The code should be something like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('$http', 'myService', function ($http, myService) {
    var customers = {};
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php")
        .success(function (response) {
            customers = response;
        });

    return {
        customers: customers
    };
});

app.controller('controller_one', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.serv = myService.customers;
});

app.controller('controller_two', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.serv = myService.customers;
});
```

Comment: I've tried something like this already, how does one use it if the service connects to an http.get.

Comment: Just the same, in my example the service initializes the data itself but it can initiate an http.get request instead.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Ofcourse, I didn't run this code but the implementation will be something like that (edited the answer)